# Prolog: Calculate summation by recursive function

Tags: prolog

I have to write a recursive function in prolog which, given two integers X>0 and N>=2, calculates the following sum:

[image]

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
sum(1,2,9).
sum(X,N,Y):-
   X>1,
   N>2,
   N1 is N-1,
   sum(X,N1,Y1),
    Y is Y1 + (((4*X+N)^2)/2*N).

 ?- sum(3,4,Y).
    false, unexpected.   % why?
```

I can't figure out where I'm wrong.

Comment: Usual reminder: You can step through your program, to see exactly what is happening and where it is going wrong, using e.g. `trace.` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Comment: "*I can't figure out where I'm wrong.*" - this isn't a question .  Also "*One of the most frequent categories of bad questions I see on StackOverflow is: I wrote this program for my assignment and it doesn’t work.*" - Eric Lippert's blog post on how to get further than that, generally: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/  also it goes `sum(3,4,Y) -> sum(3,3,Y) -> sum(3,2,Y)` and which case does that fit in? Not `sum(1...` and not `N>2`.

Answer (score 2):

To see why a program fails, it often helps to generalize the program. And if that generalization itself fails, then an error must be in the remaining part. I tried:

```
:- op(950, fy, *).
*(_).

sum(1,2,9).
sum(X,N,Y):-
   X>1,
   N>2,
   N1 is N-1,
   sum(X,N1,Y1),
   * Y is Y1 + (((4*X+N)^2)/2*N).

?- sum(3,4, Y).
   false, unexpected. % still fails
```

So the formula for the summand is unrelated to this error.
Note the first argument and its variable `X`. It is always the same. Thus the value `3` and the value `1`in the fact ensure that there will never be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would write the function being summed as

```
f(I,X,V) :- V is (4 * X + I)**2 / (2*I) .
```

making it trivial to test:

```
?- f(3,4,V)
V = 49
```

Once you have that, write your recursive predicate, something like this:

```
% this exists solely to enforce the constraints
% - X must be a number
% - N must be an integer greater than or equal to 2
%
% it then invokes a helper predicate, seeing that with an initial value for
% the accumulator.
sum(N,X,S) :-
  number(X),
  integer(N),
  N >= 2,
  sum(N,X,0,S)
  .
```

The helper predicate, `sum/4` looks like this:

```
sum(I,X,T,S) :-
    I >= 2,
    f(I,X,V),
    T1 is T+V,
    I1 is I-1,
    sum(I1,X,T1,S) .
sum(1,_,S,S) .
```

https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/DfKjFjMd.pl

Comment: Thanks for the help, I couldn't have solved it myself.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use a library, for example SWI-Prolog's library(aggregate). One way to do it:

```
my_function(X, I, R) :-
    R is (4*X + I)^2 / (2*I).

summation(Lower, Upper, Fun, Sum) :-
    aggregate_all(sum(R),
        (   between(Lower, Upper, I),
            call(Fun, I, R)
        ),
        Sum).
```

With this:

```
?- summation(2, 4, my_function(3), S).
S = 118.5.
```

Comment: The query `?- X is 3, aggregate_all(sum((4*X + I)^2 / (2*I)), between(2,4,I), S).` works... no additional code is required.

Comment: @slago yes, you are correct. You can always attempt to inline even harder. My answer attempts to show what to do if you have a "function" defined already and you want to aggregate.

Comment: I see.. but that is not what you say in your answer: "With it, you need to define a function to be summed"...

Comment: @slago yes, now I see, thank you :-) I had a reason to do it like this but I actually no longer remember it. I edited my answer to say "can" instead "need to".